# How to create Dict from array in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Have:

```
keys = ['a', 'b','c','d']
```

numpy array....

```
array = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3, 5], [6, 7, 8, 10], [11, 12, 13, 15]])
```

want

```
my_dict = {'a': [1,6,11], 'b': [2,7,12], 'c': [3,7,13], 'd': [5,10,15]}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Transpose the array, `zip()` the keys with the result and convert to a `dict`:

```
dict(zip(keys, zip(*array)))
```

Since `array` is a NumPy array, you can also use

```
dict(zip(keys, array.T)))
```

Comment: Beautiful. Might also be a dict comprehension on Python 2.7+

Answer (score 9):

```
keys = ['a', 'b','c','d']
vals = [[1, 2, 3, 5], [6, 7, 8, 10], [11, 12, 13, 15]]
dict(zip(keys, zip(*vals)))

{'a': (1, 6, 11), 'c': (3, 8, 13), 'b': (2, 7, 12), 'd': (5, 10, 15)}
```

It's useful to see what is happening when you `zip(*)` an object, it's quite a useful trick:

```
zip(*vals)

[(1, 6, 11), (2, 7, 12), (3, 8, 13), (5, 10, 15)]
```

It looks (and you'll see it another answer) like the transpose! There is a 'gotcha, here. If one of the lists is shorter than the others, `zip(*)` will stop prematurely:

```
 vals = [[1, 2, 3, 5], [6, 7, 8, 10], [11, 12, 13]]
 zip(*vals)

 [(1, 6, 11), (2, 7, 12), (3, 8, 13)]
```